# Parse Json Java

Tags: java, json, spring, dictionary, jackson

I have a very weird json response in the following format (with many more attributes):

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "key": "name",
            "value": "Hans"
        }, {
            "key": "lastName",
            "value": "Peter"            
        },..
        {}
    ],
    "bar": [
        {
            "key": "age",
            "value": "24"
        }, {
            "key": "favoriteColor",
            "value": "blue"            
        },..
        {}  
    ],..
    []
}
```

I would like to parse it into an object with a subset of the attributes like:

```
public class ClientDTO {
    public String name; // from the foo section (key might appear also in a different section..)
    public String age; // from the bar section
}
```

I already parsed it into a `Map<String,Object>` but the structure is very untypical to be processed into my object. Anyone got a code snipped for such a json/map structure?

Side info: I am using the rest template in the spring framework. Is there eventually a more elegant automatic way?

Comment: Check out Google Gson https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 0):

you may continue in using the `resttemplate` but you may use a custom Jackson serializer deserializer
You may give a look [here for deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and [here for serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: I agree, I think you need a custom deserializer that uses reflection to set the field identified by the `key`